# Unable to install wear OS 4.4 in Android studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wear-2.0

Not able to create wear virtual emulator on Android studio chipmunk.

I installed the SDK4.4W from SDK manager.

While creating virtual device the desire SDK4.4 not showing in the system image window.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has restricted the lower version for wear OS to API level 25.